# ax 2012 ssrs Query with id does not exist

Tags: reporting-services, axapta

I've created some SSRS Reports, but an error occurred in all of them.  When I try to run a report, I get the error message: `Query with the identifier 'x...' does not exist`, but the query with that name is there. 
The error also occurs when I run a report directly from 'ReportManager'. These reports have no issues in VS design preview.

I did CIL compile, DB sync, restart AOS and SSRS instance, yet none of this has helped.

Comment: Does ax run the reports using the same account and admin level as when you run them in VS?

Comment: I had this error, in my case was solved by generating a **Full CIL compilation** and then a **restart AOS**.

Comment: Are there any unique or complex environment specific setups? Such as multiple AOS's or SRS instances on the same machine. Are you testing from directly on the AOS?